# A borrower but not a lender be, I'm not a bank or university

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

From me you can borrow, but only for a while.
You've got to give it back or you'll pay a debt.
I won't borrow from you, that's not my style.
But you can give to me and some money you'll get.

I'm always found in academic places,
But public versions can also be found.
My stuff is stored in sort of 'cases,
And sometimes left lying around.

Come and visit me! I'll help you learn.
Without any fee, knowledge you can earn.

What am I?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are...

> ...a library!!!

---

From me you can borrow, but only for a while.

> You can borrow a book from a library

You've got to give it back or you'll pay a debt.

> If you don't return a book in time you will have to pay a fine

I won't borrow from you, that's not my style.

> Library's don't borrow books from you

But you can give to me and some money you'll get.

> You can donate to a library and get some money back

I'm always found in academic places,
But public versions can also be found.

> There are both public libraries, and many in universities and schools

My stuff is stored in sort of 'cases,
And sometimes left lying around.

> Books are stored in bookcases, but could be found lying on tables

Come and visit me! I'll help you learn.
Without any fee, knowledge you can earn.

> It is free to borrow from a library, and books can help you learn!!

Comment: Well that was fast. I'd hoped I was being circumspect enough with the clues, but apparently not. For line 8, I was thinking more of *tables* than the floor - I'd hope not to see that "stuff" on the floor! :-)

Comment: Minor note from my experience, it isn't always without any fee (at least to get started), but usually it is indeed a very low (mostly depending on what you are) to no fee (especially in times like these...).

Comment: @JFBM I think it depends on country, and whether its a public one or not. I've never had to pay a fee unless its a late return

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Without going into too much detail, in Germany many public places have a registration and/or annual fee (which is waived at the moment in at least three states that I know of). Doesn't really matter, I just stumbled over it during your (very good) explanation.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Just a bit of feedback, as you sound like you didn't want it to be too easy. But I got the answer from the first line instantly. I think perhaps giving away it not being a bank or university in the title limited the possibilities fairly quickly... or maybe I just got lucky with the first thing that popped into my head! :D

Answer (score 5):

What are you:

> The concept of "beer"

From me you can borrow, but only for a while.
You've got to give it back or you'll pay a debt.

> You only ever borrow beer; in a long enough session you will return "vitamin p" back to the tavern that sold it to you.  And you also need to rehydrate or you will be hung over the next day

I won't borrow from you, that's not my style.
But you can give to me and some money you'll get.

> 5 cents back per bottle or can in California, Connecticut, Hawaii, Iowa, Maine, Massachusetts, Michigan, New York, Oregon, and Vermont

I'm always found in academic places,
But public versions can also be found.

> Fraternities and Public Houses are famous for having beer

My stuff is stored in sort of 'cases,
And sometimes left lying around.

> Beer distributors sell by the case; and fraternities, again

Come and visit me! I'll help you learn.

> Learn from the founder of a university, Benjamin Franklin: "Beer is proof that God loves us and wants us to be happy."

Without any fee, knowledge you can earn.

> The expression, "[Free as in beer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21932/what-does-the-term-and-free-as-in-free-beer-mean)"

What am I?